# Linear functionals on space of all converges sequences.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose that $V$ is the space of all convergent real sequences, $(x_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$

How to show that every absolute convergent series, $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ defining a linear functional with:

$$\phi(x_i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ix_i$$

Comment: You mean $\phi$ is a functional on $V$ or $l^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx_k\right|\le M\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$$

with $\,M\,$ such that $\,|x_k|\le M\,\,\,,\;\;\forall\,k\in\Bbb N\,$ (why such M exists?) , so the function $\,\phi(\{x_k\})\,$ is well defined as the series defining it converges absolutely. Now you only have to check that

$$\phi(\{x_k\}+\{y_k\})=\phi(\{x_k\})+\phi(\{y_k\})$$

$$\phi\{tx_k\})=t\,\phi(\{x_k\})\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

Pay attention to the fact that unless the series $\,\sum a_k\,$ is the zero series, the lin. functional $\,\phi\,$ is non zero (and thus it is onto...), and then its kernel is a hyperplane (=maximal proper linear subspace) of the space of all **finitely** convergent sequences.

Comment: DonAntonio, Thank you so much! Question: is there other linear functionals on that space other than the above?

Comment: Lots more, @SandraWest: $\,\dim V^*>\dim V\,$ whenever $\,\dim V=\infty\,$ , as in this case.

Comment: And how can I represent one such l.f, which is not in form of $\sum x_ia_i$? (is there a logic behind my question?)

Comment: I really don't know, @SandraWest: all the lin. funct. I can think of right now are of that form...

Comment: And again, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Any time: it was a pleasure as I *really* loved your question. :)

Comment: Concerning the question whether *all* linear functionals on the space
$c$ of convergent sequences are of the form $\phi_a(x)=\sum x_ia_i$ for some
sequence $a$ with absolutely convergent convergent series: There are very strange *discontinuous* (with respect to the sup-norm) functionals (which you can't see since they come from the axiom of choice) but $\phi_\infty (x) =\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} x_i$ is a continuous one. Every continuous linear functional is of the form $\phi=\phi_a + \lambda \phi_\infty$.